# Autorun a script after I plugged or unplugged a USB device

Tags: usb, mount, scripts, automation, unmount

What can I do to run automatically a script after I mount/plugin or unmount/unplug a USB device?

Comment: @XxxXxx : is not an option as long as Cuttlefish doesn't have a release version for Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-distinct-flash-drive-is-mounted?rq=1

Comment: @Glutanimate: that question is about a specific USB flash-drive, but I asked about a USB device, in generally

Comment: @Glutanimate: let say that the answers from that question are helpful, anyway doesn't answer at how to run automatically a script after I **unplugged** an USB device.

Comment: @Radu ...well I m using it in 13.04, let us know If u  r interested in cuttlefish

Comment: @XxxXxx I think he is looking for a command line way ;)

Comment: @Suhaib Yes, for this I am looking

Comment: @Radu This might help you, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsbDriveDoSomethingHowto

Comment: " let say that the answers from that question are helpful, anyway doesn't answer at how to run automatically a script after I unplugged an USB device"  I'm guessing that if you change "ACTION='add'" to "ACTION='remove'", that would be a good place to start.

Comment: I tried udev rule **ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxxx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="yyyyy", RUN+="/usr/bin/sudo -u user /home/user/.bin/zzzzz"** but had no result - so looking forward to seeing some solution here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Thanks to [MinimusHeximus](https://askubuntu.com/users/126106/minimus-heximus) and the respective contributors to the [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/249064/udev-rule-to-auto-load-keyboard-layout-when-usb-keyboard-plugged-in) he mentioned in his comment to my similar question, I think I can now offer you the following answer.**

You'll need 5 (five) files for such a USB device as follows, simply filling in respective values *`<fortheseparts>`*:

**`/etc/udev/rules.d/00-usb-<yourdevice>.rules`**

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="<yourvendorid>", ATTRS{idProduct}=="<yourproductid>", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/<user>/.Xauthority", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", OWNER="<user>", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-<yourdevice>-in_udev"    
ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{idVendor}=="<yourvendorid>", ATTRS{idProduct}=="<yourproductid>", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/<user>/.Xauthority", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", OWNER="<user>", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-<yourdevice>-out_udev"
```

**`/usr/local/bin/usb-<yourdevice>-in_udev`**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/usb-<yourdevice>-in &
```

**`/usr/local/bin/usb-<yourdevice>-in`**

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
<yourbashscriptcode>
```

**`/usr/local/bin/usb-<yourdevice>-out_udev`**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/usb-<yourdevice>-out &
```

**`/usr/local/bin/usb-<yourdevice>-out`**

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
<yourbashscriptcode>
```

Notes:

1. You can capture the values `<yourvendorid>` and `<yourproductid>` by entering the command `lsusb` in Terminal -- when your USB device is plugged in -- which will list all your USB devices currently available, like `Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp.`, where **8087** is the **VendorID** and **07da** is the **ProductID**.
2. And `<yourdevice>` can be any **arbitrary** name you may choose for your USB device, for example, I chose to use the generic name "**keyboard**" when creating such  files for my USB keyboard which required applying a different keyboard layout whenever it's plugged in.
3. In some scenarios, it may not be necessary to use the `ACTION=="remove"` line in the udev rules file, and hence the associated 2 (two) "`out`" files, when you don't need to do anything (e.g. reverse a change made when the device is plugged in) after the device is plugged out.
4. Some display managers store the `.Xauthority` outside the user home directory. You will need to update the `ENV{XAUTHORITY}` accordingly. As an example GNOME Display Manager looks as follows:

   ```
   $ printenv XAUTHORITY
   ```

   ```
   /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
   ```

Comment: This looks wrong from my novice perspective. Don't those clauses have to be on the same line?

Comment: This works: ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="...", ATTRS{idProduct}=="...", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/<user>/.Xauthority", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", RUN+="<script>"

Comment: @nafg: from my novice perspective, it shouldn't make any difference if you put all those in one line (using comma as separator) in udev rules file, but I see that you have added XAUTHORITY and DISPLAY parameters to udev rules, which might work for you or somebody else, in which case I wonder if they are no longer necessary in the two script files below.

Comment: yes that's the point, you no longer need the intermediate script (except perhaps to put the actual script in the background) since udev lets you set environment. Also my understanding from the udev docs is that each line is an independent rule, lines in a file are not combined.

Comment: @nafg: Thanks for your valuable contribution. I moved these environments to udev rule and it worked for me too. Also, I moved the scripts to /usr/local/bin as I began encountering problems after I moved my /home folder to a separate partition on its own (probably because it wasn't mounted earlier). It seems using line breaks in udev rules doesn't pose any problems at least in my system (Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit) and I prefered this for readability.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure it's only running for the specified device and not other devices? I haven't found docs that support that. For ex. http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html says "Be aware that udev does not support any form of line continuation. Do not insert any line breaks in your rules, as this will cause udev to see your one rule as multiple rules and will not work as expected."

Comment: Interesting indeed. This is my first work with udev and it seems you're right although this udev rule works in spite of breaching a rule about udev rules ;-) Just in case, I should better edit that udev rule accordingly.

Comment: How to make the script executed only once?

Comment: @MUYBelgium I think what you're asking contradicts the very logic of udev rules, which "RUN" a script every time udev detects an "ACTION" by "{idVendor}{idProduct}". So when a certain USB keyboard is plugged in or unplugged the keyboard layout is changed accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The [file manager SpaceFM](http://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/) allows that. See *Auto Run* settings, for example [*Auto Run | On Mount*](http://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/spacefm-manual-en.html#devices-settings-runm) or [*Auto Run | On Unmount*](http://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/spacefm-manual-en.html#devices-settings-runu).