# Controlling a loop and saving the output for each event

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, live-usb, programming

How can I control a loop and read live feed from a usb port and save each of the output when the usb is inserted or removed. I know the code below can be improved, please assist.

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date)
HOST=$(hostname)

if [ -n "$(lsusb | grep SiGma)" ];
then
    echo "Signal connected at { $time }   Hosted by: $HOST"
    echo "__________________________________________________"
else    
    echo "Signal disconnected at { $time }   Hosted by: $HOST"
    echo "__________________________________________________"
fi
```

Comment: You might be interested in udev configuration. Udev can be set up to run a script every time a certain device or type of device is connected/disconnected.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What is it that your code does not do, but you would like it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Make your script to look something like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date)
HOST=$(hostname)

if [ -n "$(lsusb | grep SiGma)" ];
then
    echo "SiGma connected at { $time }   Hosted by: $HOST" >> ~/sigma.log
else    
    echo "SiGma disconnected at { $time }   Hosted by: $HOST" >> ~/sigma.log
fi
```

After follow [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/284224/147044) or [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/25071/147044) to autorun the script after you've plugged or unplugged an USB device. You will see the results in`~/sigma.log` file when an USB device having the "SiGma" string in the short plaintext description will be plugged or unplugged.