# How can I run a script when I unmount a particular usb drive?

Tags: 12.10, usb, mount, scripts, rsync

I am trying to sync between a folder and usb drive, so that

a) when I plug in a particular usb drive, a script runs to copy any newer files from the usb to the folder; and

b) when I unmount the drive (click eject in nautilus), a script runs to copy any newer files from the folder to the usb.

I am confident that I can use udev and rsync to accomplish part a), but how can I achieve part b)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autorun a script after I plugged or unplugged an USB device](http://askubuntu.com/questions/284224/autorun-a-script-after-i-plugged-or-unplugged-an-usb-device)

Comment: @radu I dont like the answer given >:-D  With the upstart it is probably possible too: you can create events on creation and deletion of files (and an umount removes a directory :) ) If I got time Ill add it to that one ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't like as well, but what can I do... The question is the same.

Comment: It's similar, but I'm not sure that it's the same. I'm looking to run a script when a *particular* usb is ejected. The other question is dealing with plugging and unplugging in general.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate answer has most of what's necessary. Comments welcome. Plug it in to get the ids:

```
lsusb
```

replace the ids and tell it what scripts.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="09da", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0260", OWNER="{userid}", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-copy-add.sh"
ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{idVendor}=="09da", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0260", OWNER="{userid}", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-copy-remove.sh"
```

The usb-copy scripts could be done in multiple ways. They will look something like the following. This is the remove. Reverse things for the add (does not work recursively):

```
#!/bin/sh
localf={/your/local/folder/}
for x in `ls -1 "$localf"`
do
    file=`basename $x`
    cd {mounted dir}
    if [ "$file" -nt "$x" ]
    then
        cp "$file" "$localf"
    fi
done
```

or from superuser [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/341288/copying-a-file-only-when-it-is-newer-than-the-destination) there is a [link](http://beginnerlinuxtutorial.com/help-tutorial/basic-linux-commands/cp-linux-copy-command/) that describes cp --update (with -r recursive). This is the remove, reverse for the add:

```
cp -r -u {mounted dir} {/your/local/folder/}
```

also from the same superuser [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/341288/copying-a-file-only-when-it-is-newer-than-the-destination), this is the remove, reverse for the add:

```
rsync --progress -r -u {mounted dir} {/your/local/folder/}
```

Hare are some other copy [ideas](https://www.google.com/search?q=copy%20newer%20files%20script).