# execute a shell script when USB is connected

Tags: usb, scripts

I am working on an application which deals with all kinds of USB storage devices(such as taking backup, updating *DataLogFile* etc)

My problem is :

I want to write a **shell script** which is **stored in this USB drive**(As usb is at center of my project so USB is going to be same but PC's will change) AND this script should be **executed as soon as the USB drive is connected to my Linux system**.I will not need any kind of "root" or "sudo" permissions for other tasks which I am going to do in this shell script.

Comment: But in that question the script is stored on computer ..I want to store it on That "USB DRIVE".

Comment: You will need to put something on the computer, because for good security reasons Ubuntu will not automatically run a script on the USB stick unless you add a rule akin to the one in the link to compel it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`udev` rules described in the other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/284224/1116) to run a local script. The local script can look for a file on the newly-mounted device and execute it.

(That's kind of risky for security if you think about it.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!But this means I can not make it completely USB dependent..I have to make some changes in my PC?

Comment: Correct. Ubuntu by default will not automatically run  scripts off a USB device. You will need to configure it to do so.

Comment: Okay..Anyway Thanks a lot! I will try your solution!