# Automatically switch to Singstar Microphones when they're plugged in

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, microphone, ultrastar-deluxe

I am running a media computer for my sharehouse and since singstar has been so popular I want to run Ultrastar for everyone too.  The problem is that getting the microphones set up can be finicky and a pain, even for me, let alone those who are even less used to digging [around](http://sourceforge.net/p/ultrastardx/wiki/Setup%20Singstar%20Microphones%20(Linux)/).

These instructions on this page always work for Ubuntu.  First to set up the audio by doing these steps:

1. Connect the singstar usb adapter and microphones.
2. Open up your sound settings ('Sound' in unity)
3. Navigate to Hardware tab and select the singstar microphones (make sure Profile is Stereo Input, not Mono!)
4. Switch to Input tab and choose singstar mics as input.
5. Set Upper input volume to about 80%.

Then I need to change the settings within Ultrastar Deluxe:

1. Start UltraStar Deluxe and head to Tools, then Options and after that to Record.
2. Choose USB Mic Serial.
3. Assign players to each channel. Thereto change left channel to 1 (first player) and right channel to 2 (second player). The channel numbers represent the players ingame. Player 1: Blue, Player 2: Red, Player 3: Green and so on.
4. Check if players numbers 1 and 2 aren't selected at any other soundcard to avoid multiple inputs.
5. Each player should just be assigned once. Scroll through the whole soundcard list to ensure that.

Such a pain.  If there is a way to set it up just once, run a script (either manually or automatically) to make this easier I will appreciate it.  [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284224/autorun-a-script-after-i-plugged-or-unplugged-a-usb-device) looks promising, but I'm unsure how to apply it in this case.  Thank-you!  Sorry if this is too much / not enough information.

I'm running verions 14.04 of Ubuntu under the hood, if that's helpful.